# Get other property in class of bound property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

If I got a nested class that I am binding to, how could I retrieve that parent class. For example, I have bound to SecondClass.ImageSource. I now want to get the information of the SecondClass when I click on the Image, how can I achieve this?

I would like to change the SecondClass property, but the problem is that I have a grid of the same image items.

The binding of the image works already.

Xaml:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=SecondClass.ImageSource}" Width="48" Height="48" MouseUp="Image_MouseUp_1" />
```

Code:

```
public class FirstClass {
    public int number { get; set; }
    public SecondClass SecondClass

}

public class SecondClass {
    public ImageSource ImageSource { get; set; }
}


private void Image_MouseUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
     FirstClass item = ????        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only bind to `SecondClass.ImageSource` because the `DataContext` of the `Image` is an instance of `FirstClass`. So in the handler you only need to cast it:

```
private void Image_MouseUp_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
     FirstClass item = (sender as Image).DataContext as FirstClass;
     //<Change item.SecondClass or do whatever you want>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Data Object either needs to know it's parent object, or you can use a `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` binding to reference a parent object. For example

```
<Window x:Name="RootWindow" DataContext="{Binding FirstClass}">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding SecondClass.SomeProperty}">

        <!-- Binding using ElementName -->
        <Button Context="{Binding ElementName=RootWindow, 
                Path=DataContext.SecondClass}" />

        <!-- Binding using RelativeSource -->
        <Button Context="{Binding RelativeSource=
                {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, 
                Path=DataContext.SecondClass}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```